# Vba code to set labels on a Chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, label

I am encountering a problem with the following code:

```
Sub newC()
Dim ch As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim objLabels As DataLabels
Dim objLabel As DataLabel

Range("B65", "I66").Select

Set ch = Charts.Add

ch.ChartTitle = "Prova"
conta = 1
For Each s In ch.SeriesCollection
    s.HasDataLabels = True
    s.Points(conta).DataLabel.Position = xlLeft
    conta = conta + 1

    Set objLabels = s.DataLabels
    For Each objLabel In objLabels
        objLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionLeft
    Next objLabel
Next s
End Sub
```

The problem arise when setting the label position:

```
objLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionLeft
```

and it says:

> Method position of dataLabel object failed.

Do anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is a column chart which unfortunately doesn't have the xlLabelPositionLeft; given that you don't mention the chart type I'll assume you're dealing with a column chart.  The only valid label positions for a column chart are: xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd, xlLabelPositionInsideEnd, xlLabelPositionCenter, and xlLabelPositionInsideBase.  You can see that these are the only selections provided when you manually right click on a column chart data label and then select the 'Format Data Labels' tab.  This shows these options with a radio button adjacent to each allowing for only one of these possibilities.

So something like the following works for me:

```
Sub newC()
  Dim ch As Chart

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("B65", "I66")

  Set ch = Charts.Add
  ch.SetSourceData Source:=rng
  ch.HasTitle = True
  ch.ChartTitle.Text = "Prova"

  Dim s As Series
  Dim objLabels As DataLabels
  Dim objLabel As DataLabel
  For Each s In ch.SeriesCollection
      s.HasDataLabels = True
      Set objLabels = s.DataLabels
      For Each objLabel In objLabels
          objLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
      Next objLabel
  Next s

End Sub
```

These label positions might not be what you hoped for.  But having said that you can adjust the margin alignment to get something close to what you want - in your case by setting the right margin label alignment to shift the label to the left.