# Chart data label font size selection during export in VBA

Tags: vba, export, powerpoint

Id like to be able to change the font size of the datalabels to size 14 while keeping the original text color formatting (some is white, some is black). Anyone have an idea of how I can accomplish this?

````
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim SldIndex As Integer

    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
  
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPTApp.Visible = True

    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

    SldIndex = 1

    For Each Chrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

        Chrt.Copy

        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(SldIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
            PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
        With PPTPres.Slides(SldIndex).Shapes("Chart 1")
            .Top = 150
            .Left = 350
            .Height = 250
            .Width = 350
            .Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        End With
        
        SldIndex = SldIndex + 1
        
    Next Chrt


End Sub```
````

Comment: How did you originally apply the mixed color formatting to the datalabels?

Comment: Just by hand in excel. I created a dashboard with 6 charts.

Comment: Is it the font size or the bold (or both?) which causes the color to reset?  Have you tried using the `Characters` property to set those? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.textframe.characters  Typically that avoids resetting mixed-format text to the default.  You might need to address each item individually though...

Comment: So I used this as an example for the title: .Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 20

Comment: It works for the title and the legend, but I can't seem to call the data labels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681728/vba-code-to-set-labels-on-a-chart has some code looping over data labels